# How do I assign a palette to a PIL.Image that is alpha blended in Python with Tk?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have two images both as numpy.ndarrays, one is grayscale and one is RGB color data.  I want to show these two images in a Tk GUI (I'm using the Canvas object), but I want to blend them together with an alpha channel.  I know how to transform the grayscale image to an RGB format so PIL.Image.blend() can work with them, but the problem is then setting a palette to the RGB that came from the grayscaled image.  I need to do this fairly quickly, as the GUI will adjust the palette "in real time", do things like changing the gamma factor and similar operations.

I can do everything I want: build a palette on the fly, efficiently set it to the Image object and update the PhotoImage object, and redraw the contents to the canvas (or at least have the canvas respond appropriately).  But when I then try to include the RGB image and alpha blending things break.

A single example is somewhat hard to give, since it's an involved GUI applet -- so I was hope that was clear.  But I can try to make a MWE if it's unclear?

I tried following examples in the PIL documentation.

I've tried to make an MWE.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy as np

class MWE(ttk.Frame):
    NCOL = 256
    DIM = 1000

    H = 500
    W = 500
    
    ALPHA = 0.5
    
    def __init__(self):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, tk.Tk())

        
        # these will be taken from cursor postion
        bias = 0.5
        contrast = 1.0

        # create some dummy images:
        yim, xim = np.mgrid[:self.DIM, :self.DIM]

        
        # a gray image that increase along "x"
        gray_image = ((xim/self.DIM)*self.NCOL).astype(np.uint8)
        
        # trun the gray image into an RGB by replicating the R, G, and B
        # to all be the same values
        gray_image = np.repeat(gray_image[:, :, np.newaxis], 3, axis=2)

        
        np.random.seed(1)
        # an RGB image that increases along "y" and random in other channels
        R = ((yim/self.DIM)*self.NCOL).astype(np.uint8)
        G = ((1-yim/self.DIM)*self.NCOL).astype(np.uint8)
        B = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(self.DIM,self.DIM), dtype=np.uint8)
        rgb_image = np.asarray([R, G, B], dtype=np.uint8)
        
       
        # a dummy RGB image
        rgb_image = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(1000,1000,3), dtype = np.uint8)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, height=self.H, width=self.W)
        self.canvas.pack()

        # simple palette.  The lower-case stuff is constant
        self.palette = np.linspace(0, 1, self.NCOL)
        
        # the uppercase stuff will change with mouse event
        self.PALETTE = np.clip((self.palette-bias)*contrast+0.5, 0, 1)
        self.PALETTE = (self.PALETTE*self.NCOL).astype(np.uint8)
        self.PALETTE = list(np.repeat(self.PALETTE, 3))


        # make PIL images
        self.grayImage = Image.fromarray(gray_image, mode='RGB')
        self.rgbImage = Image.fromarray(rgb_image, mode='RGB')

        # add the palette
        self.grayImage.putpalette(self.PALETTE)
        
        # alpha blended image
        self.Image = Image.blend(self.grayImage, self.rgbImage, self.ALPHA)
        #self.Image = self.grayImage
        

        # add the photo image to the canvas
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.Image)
        self.wID = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo)
        
        self.canvas.bind("<Motion>", self.adjustPalette)


        self.pack()

    def adjustPalette(self, event):
        bias = event.x/self.W
        contrast = event.y/self.H*20.
        
        self.PALETTE = np.clip((self.palette-bias)*contrast+0.5, 0, 1)
        self.PALETTE = (self.PALETTE*self.NCOL).astype(np.uint8)
        self.PALETTE = list(np.repeat(self.PALETTE, 3))


        self.grayImage.putpalette(self.PALETTE)

        self.Image = Image.blend(self.grayImage, self.rgbImage,
                                 self.ALPHA)
        #self.Image = self.grayImage

        self.photo.paste(self.Image)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MWE()
    app.mainloop()
```

but the line `self.grayImage.putpalette()` will fail because the mode of the grayImage is "RGB", and PIL.Image.putpallete() seems to require "L".  I can make it "L", but then the Image.blend will fail.

Comment: So, what you're saying is, you don't want the grayscale treated as 8-bit grayscale, you want it to be treated as an 8-bit palettized image.  Yes?  PIL has an ImagePalette module that should help.

Comment: Maybe?  Maybe I lack the vocabulary to answer cogently.  I know how to treat the grayscale as either simple 8bit or 24bit and just make the R, G,B channels the same thing (ie gray).  But it seems to use Image.blend the The two images must have the same mode (ie RGB in this case).  But the putpallete method gives an error if the mode is not L, LA, P, or PA (ie RGB is not allowed).  I haven’t tried the ImagePalette module yet, cause PILs dox give the impression it’s not completed (so I wasn’t sure how to do it exactely).  But I can give it a try if you think that’s best.

Comment: Thanks Tim for helping!  I ran out of chars in the previous!!! ;)

Comment: You youngsters don't remember, but in the early days of the GUI systems (early 90s), video memory was way WAY too expensive to do true color.  All frame buffers, and virtually all bitmaps, had 8 bits per pixel, where the pixel value was looked up in a palette.  I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I think so.  I'm trying to emulate the behavior of a GUI from the 90s, so I appreciate the concern. Maybe I misspoke when I said "true color".  I just mean a np.uint8 for each R, G, and B.  But the problem seems to be, you cannot set a palette to a PIL.Image object unless it is a grayscale mode.  SO, I can make it a grayscale mode, however the Image.blend() method only works iff both images have the same mode, and one of my images is an RGB mode.

Comment: Bear in mind that operating on a palettized image when your frame buffer is true color is NOT a fast operation these days.  You don't have hardware assist, so the graphics driver has to do the pixel-by-pixel lookups that you could be doing.  Have you tried doing the operations yourself manually, as numpy arrays?

Comment: I did not, because I assume that any arithmetic operations would be more costly than pixel lookups.  Particularly since 1. My images are potentially large (10k by 20k pixels), 2. The arithmetic I’m doing is logarithms, and 3. The PIL library has the palette functionality (why would they build this if it’s so better to do the pixel manipulation in numpy?).  

If it’s truly impossible to adjust a palette for an RGB image, which it seems to be, then I’ll do the manual thing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I think I sorted it out.

(1) It is true that `Image.putpallete()` requires only mode = L, P (or LA, PA).

(2) It is true that to alpha blend two `Image`s, they both need to have the same mode.

Therefore, you naively cannot blend where you also change the palette in "real time".  But, I figured it a "work around".  Firstly, keep the grayscale `Image` object as "L" type (as grayscale would imply).  Second, adjust the palette however you like.  Third, in the step for blending, do the conversion from "L" -> "RGB" type:

```
# update the palette to the gray scale image
self.gray_Image.putpalette(list(palette))

# blend the now-palettized gray with the RGB
self.image = Image.blend(self.gray_Image.convert("RGB"), self.rgb_Image,
                         self.alphaVar.get())
       
# put the blended image into the Photo object (this updates the tk.Canvas)
self.photo.paste(self.image)
```

Thanks again to Tim for helping me sound things out.